# Flutter install error, "Bad state: Future already completed"

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to install Flutter on Mac but I am getting an error, "Bad state: Future already completed".  Below is my output of "flutter doctor -v" Any ideas what I should try on how to troubleshoot this?

```
MacBook-Pro:~$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/tortilla/dev/programs/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

⣾Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:490:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:844:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:851:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:872:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40515) you can run `flutter config --no-analytics` to disable requests to google analytics. I had to restart the terminal after doing this. Commands such as `flutter doctor` then seemed to work.

However, if you still receive issues with `flutter build` or `flutter pub get` this is probably due to a bug in the Dart Pub library mentioned in this [Dart issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2779). The problem lies with some network requests that `dart pub get` seems to make.

On my Mac, the problem was triggered by Avast seeming to block these requests. Replacing Avast with another AV and using the Mac's built-in Firewall seemed to workaround this issue.
This is perhaps a temporary workaround at best as changing your AV program is an extreme solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a firewall issue

If you are in China see https://flutter.io/community/china

If you are using a self-signed certificate see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15014

Answer (score 0):

In my case (China), using a local mirror according to the instruction in [Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579279/987846) was not enough.

While running `flutter doctor`, I had to turn on a VPN (I use Astrill) and switch to StealthVPN mode to fix this.

Refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14866) and jump to ScholarChild's comment.